# Tutorial on GIT with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I'm trying to understand how to use GIT with Xcode 4.2.

I haven't been using GIT actively, but while I was walking through a couple of git operations mentioned [in this link](http://book.git-scm.com/3_normal_workflow.html) it appears that I have a single repository with many projects in it and a recent project in a repository all by itself.

I want to carefully take the project I am currently working on and put it into its own repository so I can safely leverage some of the branching capabilities.

I'm hesitant to begin until I have a better understanding of what's going on. I'd like to know how much is handled within Xcode and what I have to do at the command line.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn how to use Git independently and use the command line and just ignore XCode's integration.

Comment: echo'ing what mahojids said - learn it from the command line.  It will pay you back. Personally, I went through http://progit.org/ book.  First few chapters get you going.  After that, all guis make sense.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. I have been looking for something like this Pro Git Book. It's a little long, but it looks like and easy read, based on my reading the article by Scott Chacon that you linked to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@manojids comment to learn a source control system (like git) outside of a specific editors integration is a good point.  Try to understand the source control system.  The integration is a convenience, not a crutch.

Outside of that advice, apple has some docs outlining specifics of how XCode works with git.  Here's the link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

A good online resource is the pro git book available here:

http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn and understand Git and its concepts in detail then this book would be best for you [here is the link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started).

Or you can have a drill on it practically if you follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7).

I hope you will get help.